# Why does my 113th Congress Shapefile match up with the wrong districts across the country?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I downloaded a Shapefile from the Census on the 113th congress broken down by district nationally: `http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGERrd13_st/nation/tl_rd13_us_cd113.zip`

Within the .dbf file, there were no good indicators of how the districts are normally laid out (Eg. PA-15); each state was assigned a number and then a congressional district, so I figured out what the state codes meant (based on other census shapefiles and how many districts were in each state and made a new column that I'm 99.9% sure is right based on the information given. The first four rows are what came with the shapefile and the last highlighted row is what I added:

[Modified DBF.jpg](http://awesomescreenshot.com/064y82656)

And here's what it looks like when I run a query for the districts that I've defined as Pennsylvania:

["Pennsylvania" GIS.jpg](http://awesomescreenshot.com/067y81c6f)

Pretty sure that's not what Pennsylvania looks like! Can't figure it out -- because, again, I'm really sure that I defined each state's number as the proper actual state. Any ideas as to what might be wrong?

And sorry about all the links to pictures -- since this is my first post, I'm not allowed to post any images or more than two links yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you identify 42 as Pennsylvania's state FIPS code? Here's a list of the state FIPS codes: http://www.bls.gov/lau/lausfips.htm

Comment: I did! And thanks for the list; I didn't have that at first. So any idea as to why my list when I narrow the state to 42 still gives me the broken picture that I posted above?

Answer (score 1):

Setting a filter "STATEFP"='42' on the original dataset gives a good picture:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Andre! If that's what "STATEFP"='42' gives you, then there must be something wrong with something I'm doing? Cause when I query that, I get the same picture as I posted above. Any idea what I should do to combat that? I didn't re-order anything in the original .dbf file to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Its not a good idea to manipulate the dbf file outside QGIS. Try the original dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have a Mac, and I don't know how to edit a DBF file inside of GIS -- so I open the DBF using OpenOffice, add columns in there, and use that to create my map. Is there a better way?

Comment: You probably sort the database, too? That surely spoils the connection to the geometry stored in the other files of the shapefile bundle. Better use Table manager plugin or Field calculator in the attribute table dialogue (bottom right icon).

Comment: I must've resorted it accidentally, when I downloaded it again and queried to state 42, it showed Pennsylvania without problem. Can you let me know where to get those plug-ins?

Comment: Table manager plugin is in the official QGIS Repository Plugins -> Download Python Plugins, and Field Calculator is a core function.

Comment: I got table manager, but it doesn't look like I can edit in it. It still seems like the only way I can add many additional columns of information to each district is to use OpenOffice and edit the .dbf file. But you're definitely right that the re-sort constantly screws up my map. Is there potentially a way that I can re-sort the .dbf file without messing up the geometry?

Comment: I can't confirm that. If I select the layer, and then click on table manager icon, it allows me to insert another column. Field calculator in attribute table allows the same. Main difference is that TM requires not being in edit mode, and FC needs to have edit mode of the layer. I guess you will be very happy if you encounter all the possibilities which field calculator offers.

Comment: I can easily add columns through table manager also -- I just can't add all the data underneath that column through QGIS; should I be able to do that? Even if I make sure the DBF data doesn't resort in OpenOffice, it still messes up the geometry. In addition to that, even if I add the columns using TM, then add all my new data using OpenOffice, it still messes things up.

Comment: Maybe the disconnect here is that I'm not looking to edit things one-by-one, as it's far too much data -- I need to copy and paste. Thanks again!

Comment: If you want to add lots of data per element, you should look into `Join tables by attribute` which needs one unique column to match both tables. But I think that should be another question.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want PA congressional districts:

Only download the PA congressional districts - [tl_rd13_42_cd113.zip](ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGERrd13_st/42/).

It will be smaller, faster, and you will not need to filter, modify.  The census data is available but sometimes difficult to understand,interpret the file names and fields.  If you nose around a bit, you can find file name definitions and field name definitions.

Here is a list of publications concerning [FIPS](http://quickfacts.census.gov/qfd/meta/long_fips.htm) codes used in the census data.  You will have to search for the publication of your interest.  And [here](http://www.census.gov/2010census/partners/pdf/FIPS_StateCounty_Code.pdf) is a list of state and county codes from the census bureau.